# Is the derivative of a function a value or is it the derivative function of that function?

Tags: calculus

I am confused about the terminology, I see people use the word derivative to refer to both the "derivative function" and the values obtained by plugging in inputs to this function.

Which one is correct? Is it both? I feel like it would make more sense to call the derivative function the derivative of a function since that is a function we derive from the original but if the other case is true and we say a certain real number is the derivative of a function at some point, how is that even related to the word "derivative"?

Comment: It would seem the question answers itself in the first statement. The derivative of a function is a function (say $\frac{d}{dx} \, f(x) = g(x)$). A derivative evaluated at a point is a (different function or a constant; ex: $\left. \frac{d}{dx} \, (x^2 + 2) \right|_{x=2} = 4$).  In some cases the derivative of a function is the same function as in the  example of an exponential function, ie $\frac{d}{dx} \, e^x = e^x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The terminology in calculus can be a bit confusing at times. The derivative of a function, often written as $f'(x)$ or $dy/dx$, essentially tells us how the original function's value changes as we tweak the input. It's like a new function we create, which we often refer to as "the derivative of the function" or simply "the derivative".

Now, when you hear people say "a certain real number is the derivative of a function at some point", they're pinpointing a specific value on that derivative function. This value represents how steep or shallow the original function is at that particular spot. It's not the derivative function itself; instead, it's a single number that we extract from the derivative function for that specific point.

So, why do we use the same word "derivative" for both cases? Well, it's because they're intimately related. The derivative function serves as a kind of blueprint for calculating derivatives at any point. When you plug a specific value into this blueprint, you get the derivative value at that exact point. In essence, the term "derivative" is a catch-all that encompasses both the overarching concept of the derivative function and the specific values it gives us at particular points.

Comment: So can we say that when we say "the derivative of *f* at *x=a* is *b* " what we really mean is the value of the derivative function is *b* when the input is *a* but the number *b* is not technically the derivative of *f* ?

Comment: Exactly! When we say "the derivative of a function $f$ at $x=a$ is $b$", we mean that the value of the derivative function at that point, denoted as $f'(a)$, equals the number $b$. This number $b$ represents the slope or rate of change of the function at that specific point $x=a$, rather than being the derivative of the entire function $f$.

Answer (score 1):

A derivative is a function that calculates the slope of another function at a given location.  For example, the derivative of the function $y = x^2$ is 2$x$.  So when $x$ is 3, $y$ is 9, and the slope of the curve at the point (3,9) is 2$\times$3 = 6.

Comment: This is what I was thinking should be the case. But howcome we say that "the derivative of a function at a given point *a* is *b*"? Is this a shorthand way of saying the value the derivative function gives at *x=a* equals *b*? Which would mean b, which is the slope of the tangent, is not technically *the* derivative, but it is the value of the derivative at a given point.

Comment: Assuming $b$ is a value and not another function, I would say "the slope of the function's graph at the point $x = a$ is $b$", or "plug the $x$ value into the derivative to find the slope at that point on the function", or something along those lines.   I guess it could be argued that a value is a constant function.

Answer (score 0):

The derivative of a function at a point is defined as the limit of its rate of growth as the step tends to $0$ if it exists (we say that the function admits a derivative at this point). It is a number.

If a function admits a derivative at any point of a given set, you may then consider the derivative function of your function that, given a point of this set, maps to the pointwise derivative of your original function at this point. It is a function, but the two notions are often referred to by the same terms when no confusion is possible.

You may in turn (under some topological assumptions) consider the derivatives of your derivative function, and so on.